# Try-catch not working -InputMismatchException

Tags: java, oop, exception, inputmismatchexception

```
System.out.println("Enter floor: ");
int f=x.nextInt();
p.setFloor(f);
```

This code is associated with an object

```
public void setFloor(int floor){
    try{
        this.floor = floor ;
    }catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Enter only digits");
    }
}
```

Output

```
Enter floor:
hesdd
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
```

Why is the catch not working?

Comment: `int f=x.nextInt();` should be in the `try/catch` block

Comment: you want to try this `int f=x.nextInt();` don't you

Comment: Why would you expect `this.floor = floor` to throw an `InputMismatchException`? It's the `nextInt()` method that can throw the exception, but you shouldn't need to catch that. Instead, call `hasNextInt()` before trying to call `nextInt()`

Answer (score 4):

`InputMismatchException` was thrown when calling [`Scanner.nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()), you shoud catch it immediatly:

```
int f;
try {
   f = x.nextInt();
}catch (InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("Enter only digits");
}
```